# Groovy script error while reading Excel sheet in SOAPUI tool

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have written groovy script in SOAP UI tool to read values from the excel sheet and  execute the SOAP UI xml, But i am getting below error whenever i am running the script,

Please help me . I am not understanding whhat is missing here. I have added all the jar files too.

script is

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import java.io.*;

class ExcelReader {

  def readData() {
        def path = "D:\\test.xlsx";
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        Iterator rowIterator = sheet.rowIterator();
        rowIterator.next()
        Row row;                      
        def rowsData = []
        while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
             row = rowIterator.next()
             def rowIndex = row.getRowNum()
             def colIndex;
             def rowData = []
             for (Cell cell : row) {
                 colIndex = cell.getColumnIndex()
                  rowData[colIndex] = cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString();
             }                   
             rowsData << rowData
         }
         rowsData
  }
 }

def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def myTestCase = context.testCase

ExcelReader excelReader = new ExcelReader();
List rows = excelReader.readData();
def d = []
Iterator i = rows.iterator();
while( i.hasNext()){
         d = i.next();
         myTestCase.setPropertyValue("Country Name", d[0])
         //myTestCase.setPropertyValue("To", d[1])      
         testRunner.runTestStepByName( "GetCitiesByCountry")
}

enter code here
```

ERROR:

> org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed: Script8.groovy: 13: unable to resolve class Workbook @ line 13, column 18. Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream); ^ org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: unable to resolve class Workbook @ line 13, column 18. at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.addError(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:146) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolveOrFail(ResolveVisitor.java:222) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolveOrFail(ResolveVisitor.java:232) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transformVariableExpression(ResolveVisitor.java:866) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transform(ResolveVisitor.java:634) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transformDeclarationExpression(ResolveVisitor.java:1003) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transform(ResolveVisitor.java:638) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.visitExpressionStatement(ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.java:139) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ExpressionStatement.visit(ExpressionStatement.java:40) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.CodeVisitorSupport.visitBlockStatement(CodeVisitorSupport.java:35) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitBlockStatement(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:163) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitBlockStatement(ResolveVisitor.java:1240) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement.visit(BlockStatement.java:69) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClassCodeContainer(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:101) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitConstructorOrMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:112) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.visitConstructorOrMethod(ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.java:50) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitConstructorOrMethod(ResolveVisitor.java:166) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:123) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.visitContents(ClassNode.java:1055) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClass(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:50) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitClass(ResolveVisitor.java:1183) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.startResolving(ResolveVisitor.java:141) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$10.call(CompilationUnit.java:632) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:912) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:574) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:523) at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:279) at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:258) at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:613) at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:625) at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:652) at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:643) at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.compile(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:148) at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:93) at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIProGroovyScriptEngineFactory$SoapUIProGroovyScriptEngine.run(SourceFile:89) at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.run(WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.java:149) at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel$RunAction$1.run(GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel.java:274) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Script8.groovy: 14: unable to resolve class Sheet @ line 14, column 15. Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0); ^ org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: unable to resolve class Sheet @ line 14, column 15. at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.addError(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:146) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolveOrFail(ResolveVisitor.java:222) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolveOrFail(ResolveVisitor.java:232) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transformVariableExpression(ResolveVisitor.java:866) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transform(ResolveVisitor.java:634) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transformDeclarationExpression(ResolveVisitor.java:1003) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transform(ResolveVisitor.java:638) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.visitExpressionStatement(ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.java:139) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ExpressionStatement.visit(ExpressionStatement.java:40) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.CodeVisitorSupport.visitBlockStatement(CodeVisitorSupport.java:35) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitBlockStatement(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:163) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitBlockStatement(ResolveVisitor.java:1240) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement.visit(BlockStatement.java:69) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClassCodeContainer(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:101) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitConstructorOrMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:112) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.visitConstructorOrMethod(ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.java:50) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitConstructorOrMethod(ResolveVisitor.java:166) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:123) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.visitContents(ClassNode.java:1055) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClass(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:50) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitClass(ResolveVisitor.java:1183) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.startResolving(ResolveVisitor.java:141) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$10.call(CompilationUnit.java:632) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:912) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:574) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:523) at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:279) at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:258) at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:613) at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:625) at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:652) at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:643) at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.compile(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:148) at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:93) at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIProGroovyScriptEngineFactory$SoapUIProGroovyScriptEngine.run(SourceFile:89) at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.run(WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.java:149) at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel$RunAction$1.run(GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel.java:274) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Script8.groovy: 18: unable to resolve class Row @ line 18, column 13. Row row; ^ org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: unable to resolve class Row @ line 18, column 13. at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.addError(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:146) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolveOrFail(ResolveVisitor.java:222) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolveOrFail(ResolveVisitor.java:232) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transformVariableExpression(ResolveVisitor.java:866) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transform(ResolveVisitor.java:634) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transformDeclarationExpression(ResolveVisitor.java:1003) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transform(ResolveVisitor.java:638) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.visitExpressionStatement(ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.java:139) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ExpressionStatement.visit(ExpressionStatement.java:40) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.CodeVisitorSupport.visitBlockStatement(CodeVisitorSupport.java:35) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitBlockStatement(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:163) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitBlockStatement(ResolveVisitor.java:1240) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement.visit(BlockStatement.java:69) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClassCodeContainer(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:101) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitConstructorOrMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:112) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.visitConstructorOrMethod(ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.java:50) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitConstructorOrMethod(ResolveVisitor.java:166) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:123) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.visitContents(ClassNode.java:1055) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClass(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:50) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitClass(ResolveVisitor.java:1183) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.startResolving(ResolveVisitor.java:141) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$10.call(CompilationUnit.java:632) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:912) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:574) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:523) at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:279) at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:258) at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:613) at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:625) at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:652) at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:643) at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.compile(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:148) at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:93) at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIProGroovyScriptEngineFactory$SoapUIProGroovyScriptEngine.run(SourceFile:89) at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.run(WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.java:149) at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel$RunAction$1.run(GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel.java:274) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Script8.groovy: 25: unable to resolve class Cell @ line 25, column 14. for (Cell cell : row) { ^ org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: unable to resolve class Cell @ line 25, column 14. at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.addError(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:146) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolveOrFail(ResolveVisitor.java:222) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolveOrFail(ResolveVisitor.java:232) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitForLoop(ResolveVisitor.java:1233) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ForStatement.visit(ForStatement.java:47) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.CodeVisitorSupport.visitBlockStatement(CodeVisitorSupport.java:35) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitBlockStatement(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:163) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitBlockStatement(ResolveVisitor.java:1240) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement.visit(BlockStatement.java:69) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.CodeVisitorSupport.visitWhileLoop(CodeVisitorSupport.java:46) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitWhileLoop(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:233) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.visitWhileLoop(ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.java:135) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.WhileStatement.visit(WhileStatement.java:39) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.CodeVisitorSupport.visitBlockStatement(CodeVisitorSupport.java:35) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitBlockStatement(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:163) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitBlockStatement(ResolveVisitor.java:1240) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement.visit(BlockStatement.java:69) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClassCodeContainer(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:101) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitConstructorOrMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:112) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.visitConstructorOrMethod(ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.java:50) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitConstructorOrMethod(ResolveVisitor.java:166) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:123) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.visitContents(ClassNode.java:1055) at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClass(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:50) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitClass(ResolveVisitor.java:1183) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.startResolving(ResolveVisitor.java:141) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$10.call(CompilationUnit.java:632) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:912) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:574) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:523) at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:279) at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:258) at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:613) at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:625) at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:652) at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:643) at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.compile(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:148) at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:93) at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIProGroovyScriptEngineFactory$SoapUIProGroovyScriptEngine.run(SourceFile:89) at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.run(WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.java:149) at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel$RunAction$1.run(GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel.java:274) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 4 errors

Comment: have you added the apache-poi jars?

Comment: Cleanup your imports! You probably want to use only one of the `usermodel.*`.

Answer (score 2):

Add the apache-poi jars in `$SOAPUI_HOME\bin\ext` and restart SOAPUI in order to load it. If the error happens again check that the jars are correct (maybe the jars are corrupted...) checking if they content the classes you need `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook`, `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet` and so on.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Yes i have added all the jars still i am facing the same issue

Comment: mmhh strange, maybe is something related to your version? I use SOAPUI 5.0.0 and adding apache-poi jars for version 3.10 in `$SOAPUI_HOME\bin\ext` using your code, works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add poi-ooxml jar in $SOAPUI_HOME\bin\ext and restart SOAPUI. WorkbookFactory is present in mentioned jar. Please check [poi components](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components) for more info.